# Match substring with another substring in Swift

Tags: swift, logic, string-matching

I am working on Swift 4.

The requirement: I have a string:

```
var inputString = "Today is very bright day"
```

I have a file containing key value pairs for strings.

```
{
    "Birthday": ["brand day", "burn day", "bright day", "brick daya"],
    "Temporary": ["tempora", "temporar", "tempura"]
}
```

The math needed: In the app, if the inputString is `"Today is very bright day"`, I need to check if this string contains any of the values from the key-value pair file and replace the occurrence with the key.

e.g: In above example: `inputString = "Today is very bright day"`
match it with the file.
replace bight day with birthday so that the inout string becomes
`inputString = "Today is very birthday"`.

Is there any way to do this? The key-value file could be big.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to invert the Dictionary? Map the words you're searching for, to the words you're replacing them with

Comment: Actually, since some of these terms are multiple words, you wouldn't get that much benefit from doing what I just mentioned above. I was thinking you could split on spaces/punctuation to get words, and query the dict for each word. That wouldn't work for doing multi-word matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use brute force  solution it will be 2 for loop , i work on way to enhance it

```
  var inputString = "Today is very bright day"

        let file  = ["Birthday":["brand day", "burn day", "bright day", "brick daya"],"Temporary": ["tempora", "temporar", "tempura"]]

        file.forEach { (key,value) in
            value.forEach({ (item) in
               inputString =  inputString.replacingOccurrences(of: item, with: key)
            })
        }

        print(inputString)
```

Comment: This one looks more feasible, but time consuming with iterating over each values. Lets integrate this and I will see. Thank you. @Abdelahad

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to iterate through each list of each key value pairing no matter what, but here is a basic way to do replace substrings.

```
import Foundation

let replacer = "Birthday"
let replacees = ["brand day", "burn day", "bright day", "brick daya"]

var inputString = "Today is very bright day"

for phrase in replacees {
    inputString = inputString.replacingOccurrences(of: phrase, with: replacer)
}

print(inputString) //should print "Today is very birthday"
```

Comment: This looks achievable. Let me implement this and see.
The solution here works fine for just one pair of replacer and replacees. As I mentioned in the question. I will have multiple replacers and multiple replacees. How to go about that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you are storing your [replacer, replacees] pairings, but what you can do is just put translate the above code to a function and then just use a for-loop to apply each one of the replacer-replacees pairings.

func f(replacer: String, replacees: [String], inputString: String) -> String {
    // insert the above code into here
}

Comment: Oh wait I didn't see that you were storing it as a dictionary. So you will need a nested for loop (or equivalent), where you do:     for key in keyValuePairings {// above code}   and then you use `key` as replacer, and use `keyValuePairings[key]` as replacees.

Comment: It is essentially is just Abdelahad Darwish's solution

Answer (score 0):

I cant't figure anyway to achieve what you want without iterating through your key-value list, but here is a solution. I'm not sure if it will be efficient, but you may try it.

```
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)

                if let keyValueArray = jsonResult as? [String: [String]]{
                    var inputString = "Today is very bright day"

                    for (key, value) in keyValueArray {
                        let regex = "\\b" + value.joined(separator: "|\\b")

                        inputString = inputString.replacingOccurrences(of: regex, with: key, options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
                    }

                    print(inputString)
                }
            } catch {
                return
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely try it.